# How to remove first part of route in nginx?

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

I have nginx configured on server like below

```
localhost ~ elastic{
proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
proxy_set_header Host $host;
proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

With this I go on `http://nginx_host/elastic/something` I reach `http://localhost:5000/elastic/something`.

But I want to change it such that by going on `http://nginx_host/elastic/something` I reach `http://localhost:5000/something`.

I have many other services running on this server using same configuration as above, therefore I cannot use a generic method to remove the first part of the path, it needs to be specifically to remove elastic from start. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the config like this:

```
localhost  /elastic/ {                  # note the trailing slash here
  proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;    # note the trailing slash here
  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
  proxy_set_header Host $host;
  proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
}
```

The trailing slashes will ensure that `/elastic/` are removed from the url while proxying the request. So, `http://nginx_host/elastic/something` will now go to `http://localhost:5000/something`.